# Pointer not printing char[] array

Tags: debugging, arduino

I'm writing some code to take in a string, turn it into a char array and then print back to the user (before passing to another function).

Currently the code works up to `dat.toCharArray(DatTim,datsize);` however, the pointer does not seem to be working as the wile loop never fires

```
String input = "Test String for Foo";
InputParse(input);

void InputParse (String dat)  
  //Write Data
  datsize = dat.length()+1;
  const char DatTim[datsize];
  dat.toCharArray(DatTim,datsize);

  //Debug print back
  for(int i=0;i<datsize;i++)
  {
    Serial.write(DatTim[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();

  //Debug pointer print back
  const char *b;
  b=*DatTim;
  while (*b) 
  {
    Serial.print(*b);
    b++;
  }
  Foo(*DatTim);
```

I can't figure out the difference between what I have above vs the [template code provided by Majenko](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/)

```
void PrintString(const char *str) 
{
  const char *p;
  p = str;
  while (*p) 
  {
    Serial.print(*p);
    p++;
  }
}
```

Comment: `datsize = dat.length()+1; const char DatTim[datsize];` This is ill-formed in C++. The array size must be known at compile time.

Comment: As I understand, it does work for the language used in programming an Arduino. (Which I thought was C++ ?) Also the first `serial.write();` works. if that was the issue, wouldn't they both not print?

Comment: I would assume that you can use any language to program Arduino as long as there is a compiler supporting the platform. Variable length arrays are a C feature, but not supported C++. You may be using C++, but are using a compiler extension (perhaps unintentionally).

Comment: Edited code to `const char DatTim[14]` and `datsize=14` with 14 being an arbitrary number for debug. there was no effect on where the code stopped working.

Comment: Ok, then I'm most likely using C, as I don't know of any extensions I've added.(updating tags accordingly)

Comment: I don't think you use C, since you appear to call member functions, which C does not have: `dat.toCharArray(DatTim,datsize);`

Comment: That's apparently not C! Arduino is not C nor exactly C++.

Comment: Ok humm... What language am I writing in when I use [Arduino's Program](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `*DatTim` is the same as `DatTim[0]`, i.e. it gets the first *character* in the array and then assigns it to the pointer `b` (something the compiler should have warned you about).

Arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element, that is `DatTim` is equal to `&DatTim[0]`.

The simple solution is to simply do

```
const char *b = DatTim;
```

Comment: This was the issue. Thank you! I'm still a novice at this and still learning the finer aspects of language XD